# What is the best practice for blocking IPs?

Tags: java, tomcat, server

I have an application Java which is running on Tomcat 7 server. Where are many bots which try my web-application and "eat" resources. On which level should I block IP of these bots?

1. I think that on application level it is not so good idea, but in this case I can add dynamically new blocked IP.
2. I read about Valves on Tomcat and I tested this way, but if the number of IP will be greater than 1000 or greater than 10000? And after every adding procedure I must restart tomcat. This also is not so cute.
3. Where is one more way - server firewall - but in this case I can't add dynamically IP, and I think I can't make custom page for 403 error in this case.

What is the best way?

Answer (score 2):

> On which level should I block IP of these bots?

At the firewall level.  For example, using IPtables or an external firewall.

Blocking within the application (or in the Tomcat stack) means that your seb server code has to accept unwanted connections before it decides to close them.  It is much more efficient to filter out the packets much earlier than that.  It saves system resources and is better at fending of DoS attacks.

> Where is one more way - server firewall - but in this case I can't add dynamically IP, and I think I can't make custom page for 403 error in this case.

You can update an IPtables-based firewall on the fly, and quickly.

You shouldn't be giving those guys a 403.  If you have decided to block them, it is presumably because they are ignoring your "robots.txt" and/or doing other antisocial things.  They don't *deserve* a 403 response.  Just "black hole" their connection attempts.

You could also look at implementing packet filtering in your network switches, though I don't know how feasible it is to add / remove block on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

> On which level should I block IP of these bots?

There are 3 options available :

- Blocking in firewall level
- Blocking in application level
- Blocking in server level (either application server - Tomcat , or web server - Apache)

First of all, I believe **the 2nd choice is the one that should be avoided** a all cost. The application should be security-agnostic, since there are many ways to secure the application from outside.

Regarding suggestions 1 and 3, **the advantage of firewall protection is that the IPs will be blocked even before reaching the server**, thus providing much more security for your environment. On the other side, IP blocking in firewall can only be dynamic by using custom shell scripts, which can be proved quite difficult.

On the other side, **if you add an Apache as web server** in front of your tomcat, **you can use already developed modules** (like [mod_security](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_security-with-apache-on-debian-ubuntu)), that provide a lot of attacks prevention, allowing you to customise specific security rules. You can even take advantage of modules like [GeoIP Legacy Apache Module](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/), that prevent DOS from specific countries.

Note: Attackers can always "hide" their true IP, using Tor. Thus, you should not believe that an attacker will always use a unique IP.